# static libavcodec that compiled by vcpkg size too big

Tags: ffmpeg, vcpkg

I want to link ffmpeg libraries to my project as static.

When I compile ffmpeg as shared its libraries via vcpkg. size of libavcodec and other libraries are conceivable.

But when install with  this command:

```
 ./vcpkg.exe install ffmpeg[core,avcodec,swscale,swresample,avformat]:x64-windows-static --recurse
```

All static libraries sizes are larger than the shared version. Also, debug and release libraries sizes are same.

I think vcpkg compile only debug mode when it is specified as static.

How can I prevent this?

Or How can disable this in vcpkg?

Comment: static libraries being larger than shared libaries is normal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688200

Comment: There is little nuance, debug library size is the same with release files. BTW, I have added that detail.

Comment: shared libavcodec only contains libavcodec objects. static libavcodec also contains third party libraries e.g. libx265

Answer (score 0):

> I think vcpkg compile only debug mode when it is specified as static.

that is not the case but looking at the portfile it seems like optimization might not be enabled unless the ffmpeg makefile enables them.

> All static libraries sizes are larger

this is normal especially since all libraries (debug&release) are build with debug symbols (/Z7) and are built with static CRT. So unless you strip them or have your own triplet with a custom toolchain you won't get small libraries.

Comment: As far as I understand, it includes media foundation and its dependencies. Alright, does compile as static cause conflict in the client machine?